# Why doesn't my localhost website load correctly on other devices?

Tags: wordpress, localhost, stylesheet, mamp

I am developing a *WordPress* site in a locally hosted server via *MAMP*.

When I access the website from a different device (by connecting to the same Wi-Fi and entering the IP address as the URL), it loads as a plain *HTML*. For some reason, it cannot read the stylesheet. I tried this on multiple devices (Windows PC, iOS, and Android).

Any guidance on what the problem might be is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

UPDATE: Thanks to Kevin B's comment, I think I have an idea on what causes the problem. Looking at the console, it appears that the website is trying to load the assets from http://localhost/... which is something it cannot read (it considers localhost as a server run on the same device). The assets' href should be something along http://192.168.1.X for them to be obtainable. I still need to figure out how to fix this issue, but many thanks for putting me on the right track. Much Appreciated.

Comment: start by figuring out why it doesn't load. that should be easy from the windows PC, use a browser console. How exactly is it trying to download the asset.

Comment: I think I know what the problem is. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set wp_home and wp_siteurl in `wp-config.php` to your network IP:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://your_ip');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://your_ip');
```

Answer (score 0):

set your ip as base href like http://192.x.x.x/yourwebsite
set share property of website folder to everyone